# Replace Quotation in List of Lists R

Tags: json, r, regex, api, get

I am trying to get a JSON response from an API:

```
test <- GET(url, add_headers(`api_key` = key))

content(test, 'parsed')
```

When I run `content(test, 'parsed')`, I get the following error:

```
# Error: lexical error: invalid string in json text. .Note: Final passage of the "fiscal cliff bill" on January 1
```

I think this is because of the double quotations. How can I either replace the double quotes or if this is not the problem, how can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can properly assist you.

Comment: Fixing improperly-constructed JSON is a huge pain, and though I've used regex in the past to do it, https://xkcd.com/1171/.

Comment: Thanks, r2evans. I decided to just not try to fix it because the JSON is wrong in too many places, increasing my problem count pass my max for the day. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had [run into a similar problem before](https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/issues/146), and I had intended to write a quite function to use Jeroen's fix to try to repair the JSON. Since I intended to do it anyway, here's a quick hack attempt.

NB: repairing a structured format like this is speculative at best and most certainly prone to errors. The good news is that I tried to keep this specific enough so that it will not produce false results: it'll either fix what it knows it can, or fail. The "unit-testing" really needs to check other corner-cases. If you find something that this does not fix (and should) or that this breaks (gasp!), **please comment**!

```
fix_json_quotes <- function(s) {
  if (length(s) != 1) {
    warning("the argument has length > 1 and only the first element will be used")
    s <- s[[1]]
  }
  stopifnot(is.character(s))
  val <- jsonlite::validate(s)
  while (! val) {
    ind <- attr(val, "offset") - 1
    snew <- gsub("(.*)(['\"])([[:space:],]*)$", "\\1\\\\\\2\\3", substr(s, 1, ind))
    if (snew != substr(s, 1, ind)) {
      s <- paste0(snew, substr(s, ind + 1, nchar(s)))
    } else {
      break
    }
    val <- jsonlite::validate(s)
  }
  if (! val) {
    # still not validating
    stop("unable to fix quotes")
  }
  return(s)
}
```

Some sample data, unit-testing if you will (`testthat` is not required for use of the function):

```
library(testthat)
lst <- list(a="final \"cliff bill\" on")
json <- as.character(toJSON(lst))
json
# [1] "{\"a\":[\"final \\\"cliff bill\\\" on\"]}"
```

Okay, there should be no change:

```
expect_equal(json, fix_json_quotes(json))
```

Some bad data:

```
# un-escape the double quotes
badlst <- "{\"a\":[\"final \"cliff bill\" on\"]}"
expect_error(jsonlite::fromJSON(badlst))
expect_equal(json, fix_json_quotes(badlst))
```

PS: this looks specifically for double-quotes, nothing more. However, I believe that there are related errors that this might also be able to fix. I "left room" for this, in the second group within the regex (`([\"])`); for example, if single-quotes could also cause a problem, then the group could be changed to be `([\"'])`. I don't know if it's useful or even necessary.